# Updating google apps on stock Nexus 5 causes bricking

Tags: unbricking, google-play-services, nexus

I was on my Nexus 5. I hadn't updated google apps for a long time. Then one day, i thought "why not update hangouts" so I tried to get it through google play. Google Play updated itself. Then updating the rest was a bad mistake. It froze and now won't boot. I used these instructions: https://gist.github.com/deloz/6a9663ca7052fc4acf9c but for hammerhead m4b30z
and could back to stock. But everytime I try to update google apps through wifi, it dies and won't work. I thought I could just live with un-updated google apps, but now, every few days, my phone just freezes up.  Any suggestions would be helpful?

Comment: Enable debugging you your device and connect your device via USB to your PC and check `adb logcat` while a boot that ends up in a freeze. May be you see a useful error message on logcat that helps you to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Robert I will try that.  Looks like the end of my Nexus 5 as a daily driver.